# nodered http request node not completing for a particular url - stuck in requesting state

Tags: ibm-cloud, http-request, node-red

I have a node-red flow on bluemix which calls an api endpoint (drupal site on ibm container) a few times a day based on some processing. It was working fine till 3 days back. There was a networking issue with the drupal site, and http requests (default http request node with basic auth and GET) were not completing - the state was stuck at 'requesting'.

The container issue was resolved a day ago but requests from node-red are still not completing. The drupal site is accessible via browser and the api is working when tested with curl. Interestingly, if I give the IP address of site instead of the name in the url field, then the request completes. Since i am using virtual hosts, giving IP is not an option. What could be the problem, please help!!

Comment: Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: There was no error in logs but I only had few hours logs to check. I later redeployed the entire node-red flow and it started working normally - have not faced this issue again - but no idea why it occurred.

Comment: unlikely you still need this fixed, but I'd check for caching somewhere along the way.  If the service was restarted, it may be set to get a new unique identifier any your app making the request is using the old one